# Foundation 4: Orbit: Initialitation after page loading & Ajax: Reinitialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, orbit

(1) I’ve got an project and I want to use the integrated slider from Foundation 4 (Orbit). My problem is, that I only want to initialize the slider (or to start the plugin) when the browser have a specific orientation. So for my problem I need an method to start or to initialize the plugin myself.

I tried something like this:

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', 'start‘);
```

But first it starts right from the beginning of page loading and second it doesn’t start with the code line I showed you.

(2) Just one more question: On top of the question above, can I load Orbit content Slides with Ajax or do I need another solution for this? I think I need something like reinitializing-function of the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want to initialize the slider (or to start the plugin) when the
>   browser have a specific orientation

You need to do something like this:

```
if (screen.innerWidth > screen.innerHeight) {
    // start orbit when the device is on a landscape mode
    $(document).foundation('orbit').init();
}
```

> can I load Orbit content Slides with Ajax

Sure you can, just reinitialize orbit after you added your content. Something like:

```
$("#yourSlider").append('<li><img src="url_of_the_image" /></li>');
$(document).foundation('orbit').init();
```

Comment: is this accurate with foundation 5? calling the `init()` didn't change anything for me

Comment: I want to reinitialize following code after AJAX load,
    $('.slides').orbit({
      startClockOnMouseOut: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      timer: true,
      advanceSpeed: 10000
    });

Comment: @Jeff, you can refer to their new documentation here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html.

Comment: @vonv. I cant re-initialize the slides after loading more slide data via AJAX. When I re-initialize, the images disappear and only caption remains. Github issue - https://github.com/zurb/orbit/issues/141